# What does "in steps of + a certain number" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does “in steps of + a certain number” mean?

It was in this [video](https://youtu.be/2X4qySqsYP8). Here is the context:

> After tha they will have to count backwards from 1022 **in steps of 13**.

Comment: The reason for choosing **13** there is that ordinary people would find that quite difficult - they'd have to *think / calculate* each step value, whereas for "easy" numbers like **2** or **10** most of us could do it quite easily without considering it a test of "mental arithmetic". So I guess the ***After that...*** bit implies they'd being doing something earlier that might be expected to affect "mental agility", so timing whether and how quickly they could recite the correct values would be an easy way to test how much of an effect whatever they did had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count to 100 **by fours** (or **in steps of** 4):  4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24...

Count backwards from 100 in steps of 6:  100, 94, 88, 82, ...